# Adding Qt moc file to project

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, moc

Is there way to force recompile other projects `moc` file? I use visual studio, and I got one qt project, where I added other project class with interface and signals/slots (let say `thing.cpp`, `thing.h`,

`ui_thing.h`(has been included `generated files` folder),

`moc_thing.cpp` in  `generated files\debug` (because of main projects is in debug mode),

and `thing.ui` into `Form files`)

It was working ok until I decided made some changes, add some slot/signals stuff.
As you can guess included `moc` file does not recompiles. I decided to change some properties of the `thing.h` .

I copied parameters from the main projects files so
In the command line part there is

`"$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe"  "$(InputPath)" -o ".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_$(InputName).cpp"  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQWT3D_DLL -DQT_DLL -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_SCRIPT_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB  "-I.\parsers" "-I$(QWTDIR)\include" "-I.\ProductionHistory\GeneratedFiles" "-I.\ProductionHistory" "-I.\GeneratedFiles" "-I$(QTDIR)\include" "-I.\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\." "-I$(QTDIR)\include\qtmain" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSql" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui" "-I." "-I$(Boost)\." "-I.\well groups widget" "-I.\rules widget" "-I.\gui" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSvg" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtScript" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\ActiveQt" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtMultimedia"`

In the output data part `".\databaseOpening\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_$(InputName).cpp"`

In the additional dependencies part there is 
`"$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe";
$(InputPath)`

But it still not recompiles. Is there way to solve this problem?

Comment: What if in additional dependencies do this: `"$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe";$(InputPath)`? Please note that there is a **semicolumn** between values, and not a space.

Comment: @vahancho well, seems like it not helped, but thx I edited the question

Comment: You can use Qt Visual studio addin

Comment: @DmitrySazonov what do you mean by that? also, I got some problems with it - I cant even add new Qtclass into the main project beacuse of `It is impossible to add a QtGuiClass to the current project, as it was not created using Qt5VSAddin.`

Comment: You should create project as Qt project - then this features (including your original question) will be enabled.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov seems like converting into qt add in project didn't help too

Comment: well, I reinstalled the QtAdd-in utility and just made new QtGui class in the main project where I copied code(of the `thing` class) from the other project, it helped me. but actually it's not a good way to solve such problems I think

Answer (score 1):

Try check/fix project file *.vcxproj

1. add **Keyword** in section *PropertyGroup Label="Globals"*

```html
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
   <ProjectGuid>....
   <RootNamespace>...
   <Keyword>Qt4VSv1.0</Keyword> <-----------------
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. Check ProjectExtensions/VisualStudio/UserProperties  section the attribute **Qt5Version_x0020_Win32**  ( >>**Qt5...**)

```html
 <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties MocDir=".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)" 
         Qt5Version_x0020_Win32="$(DefaultQtVersion)"  <-------
         UicDir=".\GeneratedFiles" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: hello there :) its been 4 years since I last been writng code in C++/Qt, but thanks for the answer

Comment: Unfortunatley I got no chance to check it, it was the project from my first place of job